# Update immutable js nested object with new value

Tags: javascript, merge, immutable.js

I have 2 Immutable Object. and the structure is like below

```
    const state = fromJS({
       "a":"value1",
       "b":{
          "c":"value2"
       },
       "d":[ ],
       "e":{
          "f":"value3",
          "g":{
             "h":true
          }
       }
    })
    
    and
     
    const updateVal = fromJS({
    "b":{"c": "newValue"},
       "e": {"g":{"h": false"}}
    })
```

and result I want is

```
     state = fromJS({
       "a":"value1",
       "b":{
          "c":"newValue"
       },
       "d":[ ],
       "e":{
          "f":"value3",
          "g":{
             "h":false
          }
       }
    })
```

I tried mergeWith, mergeDeep but always getting the result as

```
    var state = fromJS({
           "a":"value1",
           "b":{
              "c":"newValue" // this is updating as I have same new object structure
           },
           "d":[ ],
           "e":{ // here I am loosing other values
              "g":{
                 "h":false
              }
           }
        })
```

so everything inside "e" is getting replaced with "updateVal"

what I have tried

```
    state.mergeWith((prev, next) => {
      if(!prev) return next;
      return next;
    }, updateVal)
```

this is just a structure and "updateVal" is dynamic, I have no idea what will come in updateVal. so if some structure match then replace those particular value

Comment: The expected output has a formatting error, I am not sure where. Could you please fix it. Also, please name the exact version uf immutable.js. The behaviour of some merge functions has changes slightly from 3.8.x to 4.0.x

Answer (score 1):

`merge` `mergeWith`, and `update` all perform *shallow* updates, that means they only copy whatever is at the first level of depth into the other object. That way some values can be lost, as the whole map "e" is replaced with the new map "e".

`mergeDeep` on the other hand walks through and compares collections on every level. It merges them, resulting in what you expected:

(note that merging in ImmutableJS version 3.8.x and 4.0.x has a few differences, but they do not matter in this case)

```js
const state = Immutable.fromJS({
  "a": "value1",
  "b": {
    "c": "value2"
  },
  "d": [],
  "e": {
    "f": "value3",
    "g": {
      "donttouchme": "ok",
      "h": true
    }
  }
});

const updateVal = Immutable.fromJS({
  "b": {
    "c": "newValue"
  },
  "e": {
    "g": {
      "h": false
    }
  }
});

const result = state.mergeDeep(updateVal);
console.log(result.toJS());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.14/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can explain my approach correctly. What you might be able to do is the following, take object A and object B and create a new object C based on the superset of A and B utilizing a [Proxy object with handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply).

You create a function takes in two objects and returns one object. Then loop over the keys of the first object checking if the second object has those keys as well and this call needs to be recursive when you run into a object again, but I hope this will help you out on your journey. If it helps I can write some example code as well to share.

Comment: This answer only works, if the objects are _not_ immutable.js immutables. Converting them back to normal objects with `toJS` and then `fromJS` again is possible but bad for performance

Comment: Apologies, I did not see for some reason this was concerning Immutable.js objects. You can still use the `Proxy` object with handler to merge, but it might just be better to use Immutable.js internal `mergeDeep()` function. I do want to say, I only briefly experimented with Immutable.js and it does seem it is quite mutable through `_root.entries`. It might be easier to work with [seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) and [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).